# implement JS in shopware site

Tags: javascript, smarty, shopware

So, i want to implement some javasript for example

```
<script>console.log("Hello World")</script>
```

in my shopware website, which is not the index (home) site.

**Things i already tried**

1) add the js over the body of the Website

2)  added follwing block in header.tpl of my theme

```
{block name="frontend_index_header_javascript_jquery" append}
   <script>console.log("Hello World")</script>
{/block}
```

3) added follwing block in header.tpl of my theme and created an alternative .js file and loaded it into the tpl

```
{block name="frontend_index_header_javascript_jquery" append}
   <script src="{link file='frontend/_resources/JavaScript/test.js'}"></script>
{/block}
```

What could be possibly wrong´or what do i have to change? Im using shopware 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tpl files are just markup.
A correct way to add custom Javascript or Less/css is to add it to the Events which compile the Javascript and Less/css files.
In my Example I create a subscriber(ThemeCompiler) to keep the bootstrap clean.

I assume that the subscriber is located in the folder

> Subscriber

within the plugins root and your Javascript files in

> Views/common/frontend/_public/src/js/

Please keep in mind once your file is added its present on all sides within shopware.

```
<?php

namespace ShopwarePlugins\MyPlugin\Subscriber;

use \Shopware\Components\Theme\LessDefinition;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class ThemeCompiler implements \Enlight\Event\SubscriberInterface
{

  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return array(
        'Theme_Compiler_Collect_Plugin_Less' => 'onCollectLessFiles',
        'Theme_Compiler_Collect_Plugin_Javascript' => 'onCollectJavascriptFiles'
    );
  }

  private function path(){
    return __DIR__ . '/../';
  }

  public function onCollectLessFiles()
  {
    return new LessDefinition(
        [],
        [$this->path(). 'Views/common/frontend/_public/src/less/myLessFile.less']
    );
  }

  public function onCollectJavascriptFiles()
  {
    $jsFiles = array(
        $this->path() . 'Views/common/frontend/_public/src/js/myJsFile.js'
    );
    return new ArrayCollection($jsFiles);
  }

}
```

To register the ThemeCompiler as Subscriber add the following lines to your Bootstrap:

```
use ShopwarePlugins\MyPlugin\Subscriber\ThemeCompiler;

...

private function registerSubscriber(){
    $this->subscribeEvent('Enlight_Controller_Front_StartDispatch', 'onRegisterSubscriber');
    $this->subscribeEvent('Shopware_Console_Add_Command', 'onRegisterSubscriber');
}

public function onRegisterSubscriber(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args){
    Shopware()->Events()->addSubscriber(new ThemeCompiler());
}
```

After you added these changes clear the shop cache and recompile it using the backend-ui.